# How -main works on Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am with a problem with a clojure code, and I don't understand what is happen here.

Code:

```
(defn -main []
  (clean-bucket-if-limit)
  (do-something-1)
  (do-something-2)
  (do-something-3))


(defn clean-bucket-if-limit
  []
  (let [objects (get (s3/list-objects cred "deske") :objects)]
    (let [number (count objects)]
      (if (> 3 number)
        (map delete-file-s3 objects)
        (println "no limit")))))

(defn delete-file-s3
  [object]
  (let [key (get object :key)]
    (s3/delete-object cred "bucket-name" key)))
```

The problem is that when I execute clean-bucket-if-limit only (on REPL), everything works well, but when I use the main function not (files aren't deleted).

Comment: Do you know for certain that `-main` is running?  Are the `do-something-` functions being executed?  When `clean-bucket-if-limit` runs from `-main`, what value for `(count objects)` is it seeing?  You could add `println` statements to the code to check this if need be.

Comment: is your -main defined after clean-bucket-if-limit is?

Comment: Good point Shlomi.  Or is `clean-bucket-if-limit` listed in a `declare` statement?

Comment: @Shlomi yes, -main is defined after.

Comment: @elf, thats good, I also see that amalloy answered your question correctly. may I suggest that in future questions you keep the code in the correct order, so we wont be misled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`map` is **lazy**. When you run `(map delete xs)`, you get back a lazy sequence immediately, and no work is actually done until you force the sequence by requesting elements from it. At the repl, the sequence is forced when it's printed to the screen. But when you run your program for real, `-main` returns void, and just discards the value it receives, causing nothing to ever be realized. You should use `doseq` or `dorun` or some other side-effectful sequence function if you want to iterate over a sequence for side effects, not just `map`.